# Put a hardstop or a counter for the 150 character limit on post title

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, title, user-experience

When I tried to enter a question, it said my title was over 150 characters. I started removing characters and there was no visual indicator for how many characters my title was at. So I just removed some and posted and it went through.

This is not a very good user experience. Either put a hardstop where I can't enter any more characters or show me how many characters my current title has. Don't make me guess.

Comment: I created a userscript for that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/321041/158100

Comment: If there is a limit shouldn't it be similar to a comment box that tells you how many characters you have left?

Answer (score 9):

A hard stop is a terrible idea. Typing something long and finding it didn't make it onto the screen is more annoying than having to shorten it. At least as it stands, I can go use a text editor that tells me the length to work on it. A hard stop would prevent that. A counter would be helpful (particularly if it only shows up once you're over the limit), but a hard stop makes for equally bad UX.

Comment: Yes a counter is a good idea but why a hardstop is bad? I am typing and I can't type anymore. That right away tells me that I typed too much. You prefer that people use an external editor and type there and notice the character count, copy the text then go back to SO and paste? Sounds like a hassle. What do you mean it didn't make it? As in typing and looking somewhere else while typing and you didn't check the title before clicking the button? Ok. Didn't know some people do that. Yes the counter is the best option. That's what I meant by a visual indicator,

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Lost text is frustrating. Not everyone stares at the screen the entire time they type, and this means continuing to type past the limit. I would also have to move to another interface to type the initial long title and then revise it if there's a hard stop.

Comment: Not sure where else you would be looking as you type, other than the screen. The compelling argument is the second one that you made: as I revise the title to fit within the character limit, it’d be nice to be able to do that in the same textbox, without having to round-trip copy-paste into another application. I’m something of an expert on this. Every 3rd comment or so that I leave exceeds the character limit and needs substantial revision to make it fit. :-(

Comment: @CodyGray At the keyboard. Not everyone can touch type. Looking back and forth is a natural habit if you don't, and I don't think we should require users to be able to for a pleasant UX.

Comment: @jpmc26 If you're looking at the keyboard the whole time and never look at the screen, then you won't see the counter either. I want to know who types something and never checks for anything like proper spelling before submitting a form? BTW, I look at the keyboard when I type. I would at least notice the last word I typed and notice it got cut off because of a hard stop.

Comment: @jpmc26 I said the counter is the best choice. In my opinion, switching to an external app to figure out how many characters some text is, copying from there and pasting back in the webpage is worse in terms of UX than a hard stop. What if the person is on a mobile phone? This is a major hassle to be switching apps on a single screen mobile apps. And imagine if your advice was in the era when there was no copy and paste on iPhones!!

Comment: @Tony_Henrich If you look at the keyboard while you type, you look back up when you stop and will see the counter then. If you agree the counter is preferable, I don't know why the hard stop is in the question title. I disagree that a hard stop is a good idea, and I've given my reasons why and an explanation of how it would cause problems to users. If you're not convinced by those reasons, that's okay. We don't have to agree.