# Add voice replies. With option to allow/deny them for asker

Tags: feature-request

Would be good to answer simple questions from mobile.

And please, leave your comfort zone and don't tell me you hate voice replies. Future is long time already here.

Question was put on hold for additional non related features mentioned, so I removed them and will instead answer most recent comments here on the main topic.

1. feature is meant to be optional, don't listen to, and don't allow voice replies to your own questions if you want.
2. you can't tell if it will be used by the majority or not, however you can't disagree that its used a lot in messaging software
3. amount of feedback received by this question, means its highly interesting topic anyway
4. you still might be able to combine various blocks, e.g. have both voice part in reply and code/textual part, where in voice part you could give additional explanations to the textual part.
5. I personally didnt see a well designed voice messages, thats why they cause so much anger. Because usually you dont have enough control on where you want to receive voice messages. But once it gets well designed and optional it will be a better accepted feature anywhere.

Comment: 1. Very bad usability in an office environment or anywhere else you aren't alone. 2. Generally much slower to consume than scanning some text. 3. How does that even work for answers that contain code? 4. No searchability. 5. Is this a rant or a feature request?

Comment: 1. You dont have headphones in an office? 2. 3. 4. UX should be focused on an asker, if he wants a quick reply with approach, not the code and doesn't need searchability, than its ok. If you dont want voice replies to your own questions, just uncheck them in options. 5. I use voice a lot in messages (even corporate chats) and I watch coding videos with voice instructions, so its not a rant.

Comment: *if he wants a quick reply with approach, not the code and doesn't need searchability,* --> Stack Overflwo isn't for *quick replies* and is not a help desk, a forum or a chat service

Comment: ["You have it backwards, I think..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/839601) (<--- link to expanded explanation of prior comment from @TemaniAfif)

Comment: I don't see a conflict here, quick, doesnt mean low-quality. And is still partially searchable with text in the question itself.

Comment: conflict here is explained at the link referred above, "If you make the primary purpose "helping people" (with the implicit "at all costs" that goes along with it), and let "build a repository" be the secondary purpose, the secondary purpose _is_ going to get forgotten and SO will devolve into a shitty Experts Exchange clone..."

Comment: Ask yourself how you mostly know SO. Probably—if you're the average user—because you're finding solutions to problems via Google. That's what makes SO SO. This would completely break with voice replies.

Comment: No, this is a horrible idea. Audio and video are formats that do not work for answers to (complex) programming issues. I'm already annoyed by the amount of YouTube search results I get. Let's not add plain audio to that.

Comment: As far as I know SEO, SO - uses question title for search results, not answers. Answers do add weight to the page however, but a titled (Optional) audio can add weight as well.

Comment: That's not the crucial point. You rarely stumble on *the* answer immediately coming from Google. More likely you're going to read a few to a dozen pages before you find the right solution for you. I can scan an answer in a few seconds to determine whether it's useful for me. In that time, I would have barely put on my headphones and the answerer would have barely cleared their throat. So you're slowing down the *finding of answers* significantly with voice replies. It's also orders of magnitude more difficult to jump back and forth to hear some specific details again.

Comment: Voice "comments/replies/whatever" should be added ASAP. But only if we can implement a filter so that it only accepts rhyming messages.

Comment: A *good* answer requires thought, for the content as well as for the phrasing to keep it clear and concise. Speaking off-the-cuff does not allow for either of these aspects. Errors are likely and cannot be easily corrected. Code is not possible. If a question is so simple that a spoken answer can handle it, chances are it's already been asked and answered on the site. And, in response to your remark that one may have headphones in a working environment: that's fine for the person asking, but what about the person who replies?

Comment: There are way too many problems with audio (/video) answers: Searchability, **Editability**, Accessibility, Accents, SEO, Ease of access the the containing information. Audio quality...

Comment: This should be implemented right now. So I can post answers with capitilized "Hell No!" with appropriate YouTube video. May the whole thing be in auto play? I need multiple answer to be played at the same time for a good harmonic effect.

Comment: People, we are missing an opportunity here. Would love to be able to receive voice only spam. Obviously, in rhyme, as previously stated.

Comment: Comment cleanup would be so much more fun if you could *hear* the actual anger in people's voices…

Comment: @DragandDrop Prototype implementation: https://www.myinstants.com/instant/oh-hell-no/

Comment: Oh man, I would love to hear someone yelling in incomprehensible english due to the "thicc" accent and try to decipher what they mean. That's what SO needs to become great again.

Comment: Your question might be received better if you avoid loaded expressions like "sadistic".

Comment: All such calls would be redirected to one of the 'Microsoft Windows Virus' call centres.

Comment: This question is not too broad (if it would be limited to voice replys).

Comment: So, curators are sadistic as well?  I would have thought that 'hostile, toxic, elitist, misogynist, racist' would have been sufficient:(

Comment: @MartinJames We're multi-talents, that's why we are all that at the same time.

Comment: @Tom lol, also, I forgot the ever-popular 'bigoted':(

Comment: *"amount of feedback received by this question, means its highly interesting topic anyway"* – Given this has received 40 downvotes without a single upvote… fantastic spin! 

Comment: Oh, how do you propose voice messages are going to be stored? How should SE handle the _significant_ increase in required bandwidth?

Comment: How would voice messages be reviewed? How would bots find rude language?

Comment: No doubt, the possibility of leaving audio insults, curses and death threats from their anonymous burner phones would be appreciated by some.   NO!

Comment: I'm not at all a fan of having to watch videos (and consequently, listen to audio) to learn something.  You have to sit through the intro splash screen, explaining the topic space, maybe a little about their credentials, and *then* you actually get the information you're looking for.  When you're focused on getting the knowledge as fast as possible, all of that is cruft, and detracts from the focus.  Not to mention needing to translate accents, or even completely different languages.  Having to even start listening to identify that would annoy me to no end.

Comment: How about only allowing 1000+ reputation users to voice record if you think there might be anonymous insults coming in.

Comment: That only covers _one_ of the _dozens_ of issues with the suggestion, @SamTyurenkov.

Comment: Being welcoming is very important, but the goal of being welcoming is to attract the possible most *quality* content. Afaik having speech answers would be an unbelievable increase in the not HQ content, with zero or negative effect to the HQ.

Comment: @peterhsaysreinstateMonica: Added server load, reduced editability, SEO, accessibility and ease of access don't affect the existing high quality content?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think the company should be able to handle the server load, if its value would worth its price (it does not, its value would be imho negative). Index of speech recognization results is being done by many places, like on youtube/google, it would be possible, but crap. Accessibility is a serious problem, we like visual communication. But, imho the major problem is that it would attract unbelievable amount of crap. Btw, youtube has many video tutorials and explanations, many of them are useful, but I still prefer stack overflow.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think it could be even successful, but only in a "best among the LQ" region of the Internet. Check the youtube video tutorials, I think roughly that could be done also on the SE. If the company ever does it, they will likely use an external provider for the static file hosting part, like they do it with the imgur.

Comment: So, even if it were successful, it’d still be crap

Comment: A digital call handler could manage 90% of the load: "For a null pointer or null reference exception, press 1, for scanf keeps returning, press 2, for linked-list nodes all contain the last string entered, press 3, for strange characters printed at the end of strings, press 4, for segfault/Access violation, press 5,  or press 6 to be connected to a pay-per-question homework centre':)

Comment: @MartinJames I just spilled my tea all over the keyboard... you should not write jokes like that...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar lol, I hope your KB survives.  Maybe you can get a waterproof one:)

Comment: @MartinJames It survived, there was no sugar in the tea :)

Answer (score 20):

Let's not do that.

These questions and their answers are primarily meant for future visitors, not just for the OP. You can't optimize for future visitors if you don't know if they prefer audio or not. While it is possible to transcribe the audio into text, I still don't see it as a feature many users will use. On top of that I don't see how you would describe a code example in audio in such a way that it is understandable for everyone. And if you have made a mistake, editing becomes a pain.

Maybe that model fits on sites that are primarily narrative of nature, like the language sites, Interpersonal Skills, Skeptics, Politics, to name a few. I wouldn't have high hopes.

About your concerns about other UX aspects, consider supporting previous questions on the topic, for example:

[Put a hardstop or a counter for the 150 character limit on post title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391182/put-a-hardstop-or-a-counter-for-the-150-character-limit-on-post-title)

and all posts in [quality-filter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quality-filter)

Comment: 90% of this answer above is narrative by nature as well. Lets imagine you could record a block of voice, similar to block of code, and than add links as plain text below your voice record.

Comment: I have no voice here ...

Comment: @SamTyurenkov How do you plan to record the voice of a blurry flower? https://www.irishnews.com/magazine/science/2018/05/03/news/plants-use-chemical-signals-to-talk-to-each-other-underground-1320676/ sounds difficult to record...

Comment: @samcarter, a 75 minutes video like Microcosmos movie. With only wind sound.

Comment: I expect some default voice changer in order to anonymize and protect the privacy of this blurry flower.

Comment: @DragandDrop This leaves room for the follow up episode on aquatic plants :)

Comment: "Maybe that model fits on sites that are primarily narrative of nature, like [...] Skeptics, Politics..." Oh please, god, *no*. It's painful enough having to *read* some of the answers there sometimes.

Comment: "I still don't see it as a feature many users will use" I guess this is an important point here. I think so too, but I'm not really sure. I could be a feature that many users would use. Might be a good question for The Loop.

Comment: @Trilarion: If "the loop" were to approve of this suggestion, we'd at least know for sure that the people in "the loop" are very out of the loop.

Comment: @Sam this is *meta*. I don't see this being very relevant to ANY question needing any kind of code. Honestly.... you're trying to make SO what it was never meant to be, what it never wanted to be, what the (shreds that are left of the) community is still against as well.... Just for the benefit of **some** askers. Stack was never meant for that. Stack was always meant for the thousands of users coming back later. And honestly.... voice seems like a pretty poor way to serve these.